# cocoa get drag and drop content without dropping

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

Is it possible for a menubar application icon to receive text by hovering it over the icon? I need to know how many characters are in the content before it is dropped on the icon. and if there is too many characters in the content i want the green circle on the cursor to turn red. Is this possible? What methods would i use to accomplish this? I could not find anything helpful on the [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/draganddrop/DragandDrop.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSDraggingInfo` is provided for `-draggingEntered:`, so you would have access to the `draggingPasteboard` containing the object even before the drop occurs.

As to changing the cursor, you would need to provide your own. Have a look at the `NSCursor` documentation.